# The PNG image of a TikZ picture that is generated by the standalone document class has the wrong dimensions

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdf, standalone, png

Consider the following LaTeX manuscript, which uses the `standalone` document class to generate both a `PDF` as well as a `PNG` images of a `TikZ` picture.

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) -- (1,1)
   [rounded corners] -- (2,0) -- (3,1)
   [sharp corners] -- (3,0) -- (2,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The resulting `PDF` image is (this is a screenshot):

[image: The resulting PDF image]

The resulting `PNG` image is:

[image: The resulting PNG image]

Why does the `PNG` image have different, and *wrong*, dimensions than the `PDF` file?

Comment: It would probably be a good idea if you mentioned exactly how you made the PNG. And that MWE does not generated that image. (I can see this comes from the `convert` option, but others not familiar with this `standalone` option may not know this)

Comment: see the options to convert in the standalone manual, it assumes a density of 300dpi so it you look at the image at a smaller resolution it will appear larger. dimensions are probably not _wrong_ they are just not what you expected.

Comment: It seems unlikley that the posted code made the image shown, I just get `! Package tikz Error: Giving up on this path. Did you forget a semicolon?.`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle have you tried it? I just added ` -- ++ (0,1);` and added `[line width=2mm]` to get something more noticable. Loading the PDF and PNG back into LaTeX gives a big difference (this is non scaled).

Comment: Also, exactly what is the size of the PDF? One is a vector graphic and other is a bitmap, so you'll probably never get an exact 1-1 size match.

Comment: @daleif yes but they are same again with `\includegraphics[scale=.24]{pp088.png}`  being 72/300 the default dpi settings at the relevant points of the process

Comment: @David: Fixed the code but under peer reviewed.

Comment: Define "wrong".

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: TikZ draws according to precise physical measures that the user specifies either explicitly or implicitly by accepting TikZ's defaults (which are a coordinate axis of 1cm by 1cm). The pdf image was drawn to scale; the PNG one was not.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Conceptually bitmaps do not have a size, they just have a number of pixels. As documented in the `standalone` manual the class tells `convert` to assume 300dpi which makes a high resolution image for print, but the default image resolution for pdftex is 72dpi, in fact [png files can store an intended  size for their pixels](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/spec/1.2/PNG-Chunks.html#C.pHYs) but most don't and even if they do not all systems use the hint.

so either of

```
  \fbox{\includegraphics[scale=.24]{file.png}}% 72/300=.24
```

or

```
 {\pdfimageresolution=300 \fbox{\includegraphics{file.png}}}
```

will be the same size as

```
 \fbox{\includegraphics{file.pdf}}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61976/discussion-on-answer-by-david-carlisle-the-png-image-of-a-tikz-picture-that-is-g).

Answer (score 11):

No. It does not. It depends how you measure it.

**Measuring in MS Word:**

Three different resolution images placed in Word:

[image]

When printed:

[image]

**Measuring in LaTeX:**

The Code:

```
    \documentclass[]{standalone}
    \usepackage{graphics}
    \begin{document}
    \noindent
    \includegraphics{aaa.pdf}
    \includegraphics{aaa.png}
    \end{document}
```

Measurement on the screen with 100% zoom of the PDF viewer:

[image]

**Measurement on Web Page:**

You cannot rely on the size of the PNG that you see on a web browser as they process images differently ([see here](https://daraskolnick.com/image-dpi-web/))

JPEG Image with 1200 dpi Uploaded to Imgur and seen through a web browser:

[image]

PNG Image with 300 dpi Uploaded to Imgur and seen through a web browser:

[image]

JPEG Image with 50 dpi Uploaded to Imgur and seen through a web browser:

[image]

If you want to see the correct dimension on your web browser, you need to generate your PNG with the correct dpi. See the following exercise:

My screen is 2560x1440.

Horizontal dimension of screen is: appr 23.5 inches

Screen resolution is 2560 dots/23.5 inches = 109 dots per inch

I generated a PNG with a dpi of approximately 110.

I measure the horizontal dimension on the screen with a web browser:

[image]

Comment: sorry but I do not think that addresses the issue at all which is about png generated by imagemagic convert as called by standalone.

Comment: "I think Imgur and StackExchage just zooms it while uploading it." that is essentially the whole point, a bitmap image has no natural size, your browser shows images at a default resolution (as does pdftex) so if you use images with different number of pixels they will appear at different sizes unless you specify a size.

Comment: No sorry this is not a discussion forum, the answer should address the question at the top of the page, your posting gets longer and longer with pictures of rulers which don't seem to have any connection to the question.

Comment: I am trying to push my students to learn more about LaTeX rather than use Word. This question is one reason for that, that is why I paid attention to it. I will refer it to my students later. Sorry for many  edits.

Comment: Why would this encourage them to use LaTeX? If you want to write something for you students, that's fine, but why present it as an answer to a question which it does not address?

Comment: I think it is directly related to the question. Windows and word users constantly deal with importing low quality images and it is extremely frusturating that MS does not provide support for PDFs. After a week of trying, I came to the conclusion PNG is the only reliable format to import Tikz images into Word. You got me wrong. My students are taking the easy path and use Word. They will love LaTeX if they see they can do beatiful and more accurate stuff with it, just may be with a bit steeper learning curve. :

Answer (score 4):

The `standalone` user manual (v1.2 - 2015/07/15) explains why the generated PNG image doesn't have the expected physical dimensions, and also gives methods to set these dimensions properly.

**Why the PNG image has the wrong physical dimensions**

According to section 4.6.1 'Conversion settings' on p. 15

> the following default settings are used: [...] a density of 300dpi

'dpi' is short for 'dot per inch', a.k.a. 'pixels per inch' ('ppi'). To have the correct dimensions when displayed on your screen, the ppi used to generate the PNG must equal your screen's ppi.

To find out your screen's ppi, follow [this simple method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel_density#/media/File:Square_200x200.svg) given on Wikipedia's *Pixel density* page. The method consists of using a ruler held to the screen to measure the length of a line known to be made up of a certain number of pixels.

**How to ensure the PNG image has the correct physical dimensions**

Table 1 on p. 17 suggests two methods to ensure the generated PNG image have the desired physical dimensions. Both methods consist of assigning a value to the `convert` document class option, as follows:

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert={...}]{standalone}
```

1. Set `convert={density=<d>}`, where `<d>` is your screen's ppi.
2. Set `convert={size=<w>x<h>}`, where `<w>x<h>` is the pixel dimensions of a PNG image known to have the desired physical dimensions when displayed on your screen.

   In the present case, since you stated that the screenshot of the PDF picture had the correct physical dimensions, use its pixel dimensions, namely 137x50. If you use macOS, these can be read directly from Finder.

Comment: it's not at all surprising that you get differences of a pixel or two in size (I'd have expected more) nowhere do you specify the image size so tikz has to estimate a bounding box, working out exactly the range of pixels made black by the bezier curves implied by the control points in the path is a tricky mathematical problem and almost all systems do not try to solve that exactly. a system like ghostscript can get accurate bounding box as it actually renders the image and can just look which pixels are non-white, but doing the same just from a specification of the path is tricky.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "On a given operating system all PNG files will have the same ppi's." as if I give you a png file generated on linux or windows and you save it on your mac, it does not change in any way or has any properties that distinguish it from png files generated on the mac. the ppi is just not a property of the png, it is a property of the software displaying it.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I used an idiosyncratic definition of ppi (or rather ppi's, in plural: a horizontal ppi and a vertical ppi) that suited my theory of how things work. According to my definition, ppi is a ternary relation: the (horizontal/vertical) ppi **of** <a PNG file> **in** <a certain OS> **with respect to** <a screen>. What I tried to convey in the sentence you quoted was that this relation is in fact binary: given an OS and a screen, all PNG files will have the same ppi. In other words, a ppi is a property of an OS/screen combination.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: And, yes - moving a PNG file to another OS, or even just connecting a different screen to the same computer, may affect the ppi of the file (according to the definition I used in my answer).

Comment: it is not a property of the screen or OS.  if you include a png file into pdflatex it will use the resolution specified by pdflatex (72) and make the image the same size whatever OS you have, and if you include the image into a cross-OS browser such as chrome likewise it will be rendered at the resolution specified by chrome.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: This is a complication that I did not need to address in answering this particular question. My simplified model was sufficient. A different question may well require a more nuanced model.

Comment: No sorry this answer is just completely misleading for any following readers. Like Berkus' answer it relates to the screenshot that you made while posting the question but it is completely unrelated to the actual question asked.  The latex code that you show will, if you then \includegraphics the pdf and png files back into a latex document, produce images that differ by a factor of 2.4 in _every_ operating system whether or not there is a screen attached to the machine.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: The original question did not refer to the inclusion of the PNG file in a LaTeX document, but rather as viewed on its own, say in macOS's Preview application, or when embedded in a stackexchange post and viewed in a browser.

Comment: yes but same is true whether you view in pdflatex or a browser or an image viewer, the effective resolution is as determined by that software. The screen and OS are not relevant, the only place they are relevant is when you take a screenshot of the viewed pdf as then typically the png has as many pixels as the area of the screen that you capture, it is irrelevant to the pdf and the png made by standalone.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Quite. And in this particular case the two PNGs that were the focus of the original question were one (the smaller of the two) generated by a screenshot and another that was generated (by `standalone`/Image Magick) without regard to any viewer. My answer explains why the pixel dimensions of the two files are what they are.

Comment: I give up:-) Glad you got something working for you.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I've shortened my answer. Hopefully this is more to your liking.

Comment: @Evan where will you use the PNG? To insert it in an document? If so, what type of document is it?  (like LaTeX, Framemaker, Word, OpenOffice, Google Docs?) Do you have an issue with the dimensions of the PNG when you insert it into the document?

Comment: @berkus: My prime concern was to understand the reason why the `standalone` document class generated pictures of different physical dimensions when printed as pdf vs. as saved as PNG.

Comment: Evan it cannot be your prime concern since it is a paradox.

Comment: You wouldn't know that they were different till you print it. Could your prime concern have been "verify the dimensions or resolution of the PDF or PNG" ?

Comment: I will take it a step further and propose that your prime concern was "to verify the dimension  (not the resolution)  of the PDF and PNG", since your original question did not include resolution info.

Comment: If so, you would be checking the dimension. Well the dimensions should be 3cmx1cm Since default units of  Tikz is cm unless you do not change it with transformation or smtg similar.

Comment: Forget standalone for a second, if you use article class how would you measure it? Well, in my case, I am a structural engineer and what matter most to me is final product and I would measure it by simply printing it with 100%zoom.

Comment: On a A4 paper it is indeed 3cmx1cm. There may be some small difference because of line thikness. If you use `line width=2cm`, final witdth will be appr 1cm + sqrt(1)  larger than 3cm since Tikz centerline the line wrt the coordinates you provide them.

Comment: Default line thickness in Tikz is so small I guess but there is still a thickness. That may create some small differences in dimensions and the resolution. From an engineering point it is a perfectly 3cm × 1cm rectangle (at least to me)

Comment: If you did not want to measure on the print, you can measure on the screen as I did.

Comment: Or simply include them in a Word document, İmage viewer or processor, or better yet into a LaTeX document and ask the programs about their dimensions. Which you did in your answer but  the program showes dpi not the dimension.

Comment: It is at this point you should have found that there is discrepancy and decide to post it in SE. At which point you screen capture images and use HTML viewer to display your PNG and PDF, which we cannot and should not comment on the dimensions since they are processed and modified by the screen capture and SE web page table width.

Comment: My point is PNG is generally usef to insert the image into Word.

Comment: If I am writing an article in LaTeX, I would insert a PDF.

Comment: So if you are doing this for Word, you prime concern should be the final dimension of your PNG ehen inserted in Word.