# Can I explicitly set DPI on a per-image basis with \includegraphics

Tags: graphics

I have a number of images which I want to include in my document with `\includegraphics` (or other similar thing).

The catch is that I want to explicitly override the DPI of particular images on a case-by-case basis.

That is, I want to do something like this:

```
\newcommand{\smalldpi}{100}
\newcommand{\largedpi}{600}

\includegraphics{foo.png}% default DPI seems to be fine for this one
\includeapicture[dpi=\smalldpi]{bar.png}
\includeapicture[dpi=\largedpi]{baz.png}
```

[This documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/graphics/grfguide.pdf) doesn't seem to mention DPI at all.

How can I have an image's physical size be determined from its pixel dimensions and a given DPI?

Comment: you can use `\pdfimageresolution` primitive in pdftex, but why not just use `scale=6` or whatever scale factor you want?

Comment: Because specifying DPI explicitly is the conceptually simplest expression of what I'm actually trying to do, also a) I don't know how to use `\pdfimageresolution` (does it have to be reset to the default after adjustment?), and b) I don't know how to calculate the scale factor (or how it depends on e.g. file metadata). I don't want to guess `scale=` until it works, I want the images to be *precisely* rendered at the given DPI

Comment: Put it this way, if I draw a 1.5 inch tikz arrow over a 20dpi raster image, that arrow needs to cover exactly 30 pixels. I don't want the success of this to depend on anything other than pixels, inches, and pixels-per-inch.

Comment: If you draw an object in Tikz and produce the PDF, the object will be kept as a vector, no? I don't think it will have a dpi unless you generate PNG from the PDF or print it. What you are trying to achieve does not make much sense. You cannot control the change in the size of a PNG effectively by changing the DPI. But when you resize of a PNG, it has to resample the image, which may or may not change the DPI, but possibly will. It seems that what David suggests is the best way to go.

Comment: Just wondering, is there a way to keep the original DPI of an PNG within the PDF and it will be reduced by other means when needed (e.g. printing)? Some kind of a "link" to the original PNG file? Can LaTeX do that? This will make the PDF significantly large for large PNGs, but it will keep the quality of the original PNG?

Comment: the original image data is (usually) just copied to the file and if (for interlacing or gamma correction etc) it is unpacked and repacked it is done losslessly to put exactly that bitmap data in the pdf stream, any rescaling is just done by wrapping that in a pdf coordinate scale so any resampling os fone by the pdf renderer not by tex (@berkus)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle a PDF has a notion of physical page dimensions though, right? So if an 600x900 pixel image is given as 300dpi it will appear as 2x3 inches. Right? Seems quite well-defined to me. PDF is scalable insofar as you can render it at any zoom level, but then the embedded raster would just have to be zoomed by the same factor. None of this changes my situation.

Comment: it's defined but the system is just going to take the ratio of the dpi and apply a scale factor of that amount, if you want the final image to be 2in wide it seems simplest to use `[width=2in]` than try to specify a nominal dpi that differs from the image specified dpi (if it has one) or pdftex's normal default dpi of 72 by a scale factor that results in the final image being 2in wide.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Thanks. This is really useful.

Comment: [This post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/378142/96172) may be helpful to measure the final product crudely. I know, it is not a theoretical as the information provided by the LaTeXperts here, but comes handy. :)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle you say " if you want the final image to be 2in wide it seems simplest to use..." but that's the thing: I don't know I want it to be 2in wide, I know I want it to be pixelwidth/dpi inches wide. I don't want to calculate it by hand because the image files themselves are not yet determined -- but their desired DPI is determined.

Comment: In my situation, the simplest thing is to specify the DPI and have latex calculate the image size from the given DPI and the contents of the file itself.

Comment: historically tex couldn't access that information but in pdftex, with png, you can use `\pdfimageresolution=100\includegraphics{file.png}` to do what I think you want to do it is just a very rare thing to want to do (I can't recall anyone asking for a more latex-like interface to that in all the 35 or so years the graphics package has been available:-)

Comment: Be aware that the image is merely scaled, not resampled. As the question was asked, that seems OK. But if your purpose is commercial print production, some printers don't like scaling images to meet a particular dpi specification. They expect that the images will be resampled (in a graphics program) and inserted in the PDF at exact resolution.

Answer (score 5):

Solution using [pdfTeX](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/pdftex/manual/pdftex-a.pdf) primitive and a [macro](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Macros):

In the preamble:

```
\newcommand{\includegraphicsdpi}[3]{
    \pdfimageresolution=#1  % Change the dpi of images
    \includegraphics[#2]{#3}
    \pdfimageresolution=72  % Change it back to the default
}
```

In the document:

```
\includegraphicsdpi{300}{}{figures/rpi/app_main}
```

Old solution: I used to use `\includegraphics[resolution=300]{bar.png}` to do exactly this, using Texlive 2016. Maybe that works for you. I recently updated Texlive, and it stopped working. Getting `Package keyval Error: resolution undefined.` Separate question about that, [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/392674/includegraphics-image-resolution-stopped-working).

Comment: Not that my macro does not work if you include the same image twice. If you do that, the resolution of the first invocation will be used. Don't know why. GLHF.

Comment: Instead of changing it back, simply wrap the first two macros in a `{ }` group.

Comment: Is this answer still valid? Calling pdfimageresolution doesn't seem to change anything :(