# Configure the Inkscape figure size so that the font within the graphics matches the font in the text

Tags: graphics

I would like to configure the size of a figure produced by Inkscape so that the font within the graphics matches the font size in the text.

The document uses the default font size, which is 10pt. I created a figure with Inkscape, and exported them into a .pdf file.

[image: A function y=f(x)]

I then use the `includegraphics` command to include the figure within the document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=8cm]{drawing.pdf}
\end{center}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

The following presents the result: the font size in the figure is much larger than the font size in the text.

[image: The result]

I do not know how to exactly choose the figure width (or height) so that the font size within the text matches the font size within the figure. I usually visually inspect the result and adjust the width so that both match, but this is not technically satisfactory and often off by one or more cm.

Is there a technically better method which does not use Tikz or other straightforward LaTeX figure programming? Is there a software which automatically detects and adjusts the size? Is there a more appropriate way to use Inkscape for LaTeX documents?

Comment: (i) It is unknown which font size was used when picture was drawn, also (ii)  is unknown natural size of your picture. If removing `[width=8cm]` doesn't help, it seems that you need to redraw your image accordingly.

Comment: If you know the dpi at which the images is generated, you could try this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/392675/29873

Comment: I generated these graphics myself with Inkscape, so that all parameters are known to me: font size, dpi, figure size, etc... However, I have no idea how to reuse these informations when including the figure in the LaTeX document.

Comment: What is the dpi of a pdf vector (not bitmap) file?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get the correct result by using the same font in the Inkscape figure and in the LaTeX document.

Given that I use the default 10 point font size in LaTeX, I scaled the Inkscape figure so that the font size was set to 10 pt. To do this, I selected all the objects in the Inkscape figure with Ctrl+a, then used the tool to downscale the figure. I checked the font size with the Text tool and stopped to iterate when I reached 10 pt. Finally, I saved the figure into PDF with default settings.

Then I used the following statement, without any scaling:

```
\includegraphics{drawing.pdf}
```

And the result is perfect, of course:

[image: The figure with no resizing]

Exporting the figure into a png file with default Inkscape settings produces the same result (but the result is bitmap).

Furthermore, I used LaTeX fonts, i.e. Computer Modern fonts in Inkscape, based on tips at:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/307158/use-cm-roman-latex-font-in-inkscape

This appears as "CMU Serif" in Inkscape.