# standalone tikz - proper size to include

Tags: tikz-pgf, standalone, size

I am drawing my graphics for an article with `tikz`. For reasonable compilation speed I always draw the graphs as a `standalone` document and then include the graphic.

My question is now, how to figure out the right size in `standalone`. Of course, I don't want my graphic to be to big for my pages. Scaling it always messes up the layout to some degree.
Is there a recommended way to do it? Or at least the possibility to show some A4 box to be able to ``guess'' the proper size?

Minimum example:

```
\documentclass[crop,tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) circle (10);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

How do I e.g. know how big I can make this circle, before I have to re-scale my picture to fit it on a page?

Comment: There is a similar question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/378125/the-png-image-of-a-tikz-picture-that-is-generated-by-the-standalone-document-cla).

Comment: If you don't crop it, you can set the page to, say, A4 or whatever and use `showframe` or `geometry` or whatever package you're using. Then use cropping only when including the image. I always just look at the PDF properties, myself, but that is likely not the most efficient strategy.

Comment: Thanks @cfr, `geometry` and not cropping looks like a good start. It seems like `standalone` crops by default, removing the option doesn't change anything. I am using `scrarticle`, so I don't exactly know what to pass to `geometry` but `a4page` should be a good start. Is there also a possibility do draw a rectangle over the whole page to get an impression?

Comment: You can use `\rule{\textwidth}{\textheight}  ` to fill the text area.  You can also use \the\textwidth and \the\textheight (then convert pt to in or cm).  Note that PDF is not rasterized, so you lose no resolution by scaling with \includegraphics.  Just zoom in on the picture.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Scaling fonts is not recommended, though.

Comment: @DerWeh The `showframe` option to `geometry` will give you an idea, although `scrartcl` will be using different dimensions for layout - but you'll have a general sense of where standardish margins are. Or you can just use `scrartcl` for the image. You can feed `standalone` a different class, I think, or just use a different class. You can still include the image using `standalone`.

Comment: "I am drawing my graphics for an article with tikz. For reasonable compilation speed I always draw the graphs as a standalone document and then include the graphic." Well that's exactly the reason I wrote `standalone` in the first place. I had a lot of TikZ diagrams in my PhD thesis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use option `class=scrartcl` to change the underlying class to your neeeds. Then add all options needed by KOMA-Script package `typerarea` to calculate the page layout, e.g. `DIV`, `BCOR`, `headinclude`, `fontsize` etc.

Note that class `standalone` changes `\textheight`. So you have to use `\storeareas` and `\recalculatetypearea` to get the KOMA-Script \textheight. This must be saved in a macro before the standalone layout settings are restored.

Then it is possible to add e.g. a red rectangle showing the size of the text area of the KOMA-Script document. In the following example the upper left corners of the TiKZ picture and the red rectangle are aligned.

```
\documentclass[
  tikz,
  class=scrartcl,% underlying class which is loaded by standalone
  headinclude,fontsize=12pt,% options used by typearea
]{standalone}

\storeareas\standalonelayout% save the standalone layout
\recalctypearea% recalculate the typearea layout
\edef\savedtextheight{\the\textheight}% save the text height of the typearea layout
\standalonelayout% restore the standalone layout

% draw a red rectangle aligned with the upper left corner of the TikZ picture
% to show the size of the text area in the KOMA document:
\tikzset{
  every picture/.append style={
    execute at end picture={%
      \draw[red](current bounding box.north west)
        rectangle
        ++(\the\textwidth,-\savedtextheight);%
}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) circle (10);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Works like a charm, it's more than I expected. But now I get greedy. Is it also possible to adjust `Tikz`s `internal grid'. To say e.g. the left bottom corner is coordinate (0,0) and I want to fix the right bottom corner at (10, 0) or (12, 0) to have an easy impression of the ratios I am working with?

Comment: I am sorry, but I do not understand what you want to do.